Eigenvalue of a convolution and a restriction?
Let $\epsilon>0$ be small. Let $\eta(t) = \frac{2\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+(2\pi t)^2}$ (the Fourier transform of $x\mapsto e^{-\epsilon |x|}$). Let $V$ be the space of integrable, bounded functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ that are supported on $[-1/2,1/2]$ and even. We would like to know for which $f\in V$ with $\|f\|_2=1$ the integral
$$I_\epsilon(f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \eta(t) (1-f\ast f)(t) dt$$
is minimal, and what that minimum is. Since $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ is fixed, this is the same as the problem of maximizing $\langle \eta,f\ast f\rangle$.
A little calculus of variations shows that, for any extremal $f$ as above, $(\eta \ast f)|_{[-1/2,1/2]}$ has to be a multiple $\lambda f$ of $f$. Moreover, $I_\epsilon(f) =
1 - \langle \eta,f\ast f\rangle = 1 - \langle f\ast \eta,f\rangle = 1-\lambda$.
A little work suffices to show that $1-\lambda = O(\epsilon)$.
What is (or are) the extremal $f$, however, and what is $\lambda$? We should at least be able to determine $(1-\lambda)/\epsilon$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.
(Looking at what happens when one takes a high power of the operator $f\mapsto (\eta \ast f)|_{[-1/2,1/2]}$ seems promising, but I suspect there is a concise, standard way of solving this kind of problem.)

Admins: can we undelete the AI answer? (a) In my self-answer below, I make frequent reference to it. (b) This is actually a case in which an AI answer, though wrong in many places, has some interest (or else I would not have discussed it). I do not like AI posts here (first of all, they do not present themselves as such) but we shouldn't delete something that has been referred to repeatedly.

Let me simultaneously (a) show why it is clear to me that user548030 is an AI, (b) work through some issues raised in its answer.

The first paragraph of user548030's answer restates (correctly) one of my remarks, namely, that minimizing $I_\epsilon(f)$ is the same as maximizing what it calls $J_\epsilon(f)$ (this is trivial). Then it expresses (again correctly) $J_\epsilon(f)$ as an integral on the Fourier side. Note it never uses that integral again. (This is not surprising: that integral looks as if it almost gave us the solution, but the information about the support of $f$ is basically lost on the Fourier side, or rather it becomes more awkward to state.)

By the way, this already shows that, if we are dealing with an AI, we are dealing with an AI that can manipulate mathematical expressions.

What it says then about what obtains from calculus of variations would be impressive if it were not a simple restatement of what I said (a careless, incorrect one: it's the restriction of $\eta\ast f$ to $[-1/2,1/2]$ that is a multiple of $f$.

Then it says, completely incorrectly, that a Lagrange multiplier is just an eigenvalue. What happens here is that 'Lagrange multiplier' is a buzzword in the area (in fact the name of a useful concept that can be used to show in the proof of what I alluded to) -- and a common symbol used for the multiplier is $\lambda$, which is also a symbol commonly used for an eigenvalue (and which I used for an eigenvalue).
This is a blooper, but not that a beginning graduate student with a tendency to fake it could never do.
3."The support constraint on $f$ imposes a fundamental limitation on how quickly its Fourier transform can decay. Specifically, for any function supported on $[−1/2,1/2]$, its Fourier transform cannot decay faster than $O(1/k^2)$ as $|k|\to \infty$." The first sentence is correct (in that the Fourier transform of a compactly supported function cannot be compactly supported; there are several useful statements here that go by the name of 'uncertainty principle'). The second one is quite wrong: the Fourier transform of $\widehat{f}(t)$ of $t$ can decay faster than any power of $t$ as $|t|\to \infty$ (incidentally, $k$ is a funny choice of letter here); for that to happen, it is enough that $f$ be in $C^\infty$.

Now, the function $\sqrt{2} \cos(\pi x)$ is a completely reasonable thing to try; in fact, I suggested it in a post on Facebook (with a change in constants) before a friend shot it down for being naïve. It's a nice function. On the other hand, part of the reason given by user548030 is
nonsense ("Its Fourier transform achieves the slowest possible decay
rate $(1/k^2)$") and part is qualitatively sensible but
unsupported ("...while being as concentrated as possible near $k=\pm
\pi$. This is optimal because we cannot concentrate the transform
closer to 0 due to the support constraint")

This is a little frightening. Either user548030 can do a simple Ansatz, or it is snooping friends-only posts on Facebook (or a Facebook friend is involved, likely feeding an AI).
Some further thought shows that this is not a good Ansatz or such a good choice of function.  While $\sqrt{2} \cos(\pi x)$ satisfies a boundary condition (vanishing at the ends of the interval), it is not a condition that we set, or indeed one that should be set: a moment's thought shows that an $f$ maximizing $J_\epsilon(f)$ has to be non-negative everywhere (or non-positive everywhere) as well as (obviously) not identically zero, and then $\eta\ast f$ cannot vanish at $1/2$ or $-1/2$; hence, an $f$ with $\lim_{t\to 1/2} f(t) = 0$ or $\lim_{t\to -1/2} f(t) = 0$ cannot be an eigenfunction of $f\mapsto (\eta\ast f)|_{[-1/2,1/2]}$.
Funnily enough, the fact that an eigenfunction $f$ will have to be discontinuous at $1/2$ (and $-1/2$) should mean $\widehat{f}(t)$ will decay no faster than $O(1/t)$ (and so some care will have to be exercised, as $\widehat{f}$ will not be in $L^1$, though of course it will be in $L^2$).
It might also be that there is an eigenfunction $f$ such that $\lim_{t\to \frac{1}{2}^-} f(t)= O(\epsilon)$ (for all that I know).

The calculation of the Rayleigh quotient is of course incorrect, since the kernel on the physical (non-Fourier) side is $\eta(y-x)$, not $e^{-\epsilon |x-y|}$. Again, not a mistake a student (or someone careless) would never make, but I think the evidence up to this point was already enough to make it clear we are dealing with an AI (even ignoring the fact that this is "new contributor user548030"). The rest is then useless (or almost useless - see below). Still, I am starting to be impressed even with some of its human-style mistakes (much less so with others).

Using the right kernel here doesn't seem to give something very nice here (but maybe I'm not using a powerful enough symbolic integrator :P).
Here's another way to do things: first, take the Fourier transform of $f = \sqrt{2} \cos \pi x|_{[-1/2,1/2]}$. This is
$$\widehat{f}(t) = \frac{\mathrm{sinc}(t+1/2)+\mathrm{sinc}(t-1/2)}{\sqrt{2}},$$
where $\mathrm{sinc}(t) = \frac{\sin \pi t}{\pi t}$. We could of course write $\mathrm{sinc}(t+1/2) = \frac{\cos(\pi t)}{\pi (t+1/2)}$ and $\mathrm{sinc}(t-1/2) = -\frac{\cos(\pi t)}{\pi (t-1/2)}$, and so $$\widehat{f}(t) = \frac{\cos \pi t}{\sqrt{2} \pi \left(\frac{1}{4}-t^2\right)}.$$
Then $$\widehat{\eta\ast f}(t) = \widehat{\eta}(t) \widehat{f}(t) = e^{-\epsilon |t|} \frac{\cos \pi t}{\sqrt{2} \pi \left(\frac{1}{4}-t^2\right)}$$
and so, by Plancherel, $$\langle \eta\ast f, f\rangle = \langle \widehat{\eta\ast f},\widehat{f}\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\epsilon |t|} \left(\frac{\cos \pi t}{\sqrt{2} \pi \left(\frac{1}{4}-t^2\right)}\right)^2 dt = 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-\epsilon t}  \left(\frac{\cos \pi t}{\sqrt{2} \pi \left(\frac{1}{4}-t^2\right)}\right)^2 dt.$$
Our known computer friends SAGE/sympy/giac/maxima and WolframAlpha are stumped here, but our new friend user548030 is of course completely right that a Taylor expansion around $t = 0$ can be useful here. (Hardly rocket science, but this would again be consistent with a strong undergrad/beginning graduate student in a field close to math who otherwise also bullshits a lot and makes a lot of mistakes.)
We have $e^{-\epsilon t} = 1 - \epsilon t + O((\epsilon t)^2)$ for $t>0$ (even for $t$ large). Hence
$$\langle \eta\ast f, f\rangle = 2(I_0 - \epsilon I_1 + O(\epsilon^2) I_2),$$
where $$I_k = \int_0^\infty t \left(\frac{\cos \pi t}{\sqrt{2} \pi \left(\frac{1}{4}-t^2\right)}\right)^2 dt.$$
An easy calculation shows that $I_0=1/2$,
$$I_1 = \frac{\pi \mathrm{Si}(\pi)-2}{2\pi^2} = 0.19342\dotsc$$ where $\mathrm{Si}(\pi) = \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$, and
$$I_2 = 1/8.$$
Hence, $$I_\epsilon(f) = 1 - \langle \eta\ast f,f\rangle = 2 I_1 \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)\approx 0.38685\epsilon + O(\epsilon^2),$$
where the implied constant is small and can be made explicit very easily.
This shouldn't be optimal (in fact I think one can easily find better functions), but it is something.
For comparison, for any $f$ with $\|f\|_2 = 1$, we trivially have
$$I_\epsilon(f) \geq \int_{|t|>1} \eta(t) dt = (1+O(\epsilon^2)) \epsilon \int_{|t|>1} \frac{2}{(2\pi t)^2} dt = \frac{\epsilon}{\pi^2} + O(\epsilon^3) \approx 0.10132 \epsilon + O(\epsilon^3).$$
Also consider $f= 1_{[-1/2,1/2]}$. Then $\widehat{f}(t) = \mathrm{sinc}(t)$, and so
$$\langle \eta\ast f, f\rangle = \langle \widehat{\eta\ast f},\widehat{f}\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\epsilon |t|} \mathrm{sinc}(t)^2 dt.$$
Here the approximation is trickier because of convergence issues; I'll finish this later. I think there's a closed expression that the symbolic integrators I have barely fail to find. EDIT: silly me, of course one wants to work in physical space for that $f$:
$$\begin{aligned}\langle \eta, f\ast f\rangle &= 2 \int_0^\infty \eta(t) dt - 2 \int_0^1 \eta(t) t dt = 1 - 4\epsilon\cdot \int_0^1 \frac{t dt}{\epsilon^2 + (2\pi t)^2}\\ &= 1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2\pi^2}\cdot \log \left(1 + \left(\frac{2\pi}{\epsilon}\right)^2\right),\end{aligned}$$ and so $$I_\epsilon(f) = \frac{\epsilon}{2\pi^2}\cdot \log \left(1 + \left(\frac{2\pi}{\epsilon}\right)^2\right),$$ which, for very small $\epsilon>0$, is much worse than the $\cos$ example above; it is not even $O(\epsilon)$.
In general, if $f$ is absolutely continuous with $f'$ of bounded total variation (as $f=1_{[-1/2,1/2]}$ is not), then $\widehat{f}(t)$ decays at least as fast as $1/t^2$ as $t\to \pm \infty$. Then we can proceed as before, and obtain $$\langle \eta\ast f, f\rangle = 1 - 2\epsilon I_{1}(f) + O_f(\epsilon^2),$$ where
$$I_{1}(f) = \int_0^\infty t (\widehat{\eta}(t))^2 dt.$$
So, we want to minimize $I_1(f)$.

Your operator is somewhat similar to the adjacency matrix of a path graph, whose top eigenvector is a cosine function.Was this the source of cosine idea? Considering that example I think positivity should be obtained by just stretching out, i.e. $\cos ( (\pi - C \epsilon) x$ for appropriate $C$. I sort of suspect this example will give the optimal asymptotic for $(1-\lambda)/\epsilon$, though not the optimal exact value. (Although maybe stretching out does not affect the asymptotic).

@WillSawin I was guessing basically as a slightly more advanced AI would: a truncated cosine is one of those things that actually appear as eigenfunctions, as I vaguely remember from many years of half-listening to talks in other areas. I don't remember anything about path graphs specifically - I'll have to learn. But yes, I was thinking that this is like an adjacency matrix, and a possible approach is simply to take a high power of it, i.e., iterate the operator many times on a fairly arbitrary function. But why do you suspect this might be optimal?

@WillSawin Probably a better reason to suspect $\cos$ is that it is an eigenfunction of $f\mapsto f''$ (except at $-1/2$ and $1/2$), and that these operators are starting to look awfully like $f\mapsto f''$ up to a first order of approximation.

Roughly that away from the boundary your operator is well-approximated by just convolution, so we need an eigenfunction of the convolution operator, which would be a sine or cosine of something.  We obtain a loss compared to the best possible $\lambda=1$ if it's an eigenfunction with value less than $1$, and a loss also at the boundary from the part of $f$ that after convolution lies outside $[-1/2,1/2]$ and is ignored. Lowering the frequency of the cosine lowers the first loss but raises the second, but only at a worthwile rate if you lower it a small amount.

@WillSawin What do you mean by an eigenfunction of the convolution operator? Convolution with what?

Convolution with $\eta$. If $\eta * f$, restricted to the interval $[-1/2,1/2]$, is equal to $\lambda f$, and we shrink the support of $\eta$, which is like growing the interval, then maybe we can say that $\eta * f$ is approximately $\lambda f$ so $f$ is approximately an eigenfunction of convolution with $\eta$.

Actually maybe $\cos (  (\pi-\delta) x))$ beats $\cos(\pi x)$ for some $\delta>0$ independent of $\epsilon$.

@WillSawin I'm not sure I can see how this is possible. Wouldn't the discontinuity at $1$ (by a constant independent of $\epsilon$) cause the decay of $\widehat{f}$ to be only like $O(1/t)$, and $I_\epsilon(f)$ not be $O(\epsilon)$, just as above?

Ah! I now see how to do it (up to a $O(\epsilon^2)$ term). Consider the operator $A:f\mapsto \frac{1}{2\pi i} (f'\ast \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})$. The Fourier transform of $A f$ is $\sqrt{|t|} \widehat{f}(t)$. Hence, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |t| |\widehat{f}|^2 dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\widehat{A f}(t)|^2 dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |(A f)(x)|^2 dx.$ Show by integration by parts that $(A f)(x) = \frac{1}{4\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{|y|^{3/2}} dy$. By either calculus of variations or compact-operator-something, $|A f|_2$ is minimized when $f$ is an eigenfunction of $A$. (cont.)

But what are the eigenfunctions of $A$? Again we have the problem that, while there presumably are eigenfunctions supported in $1_{[-1/2,1/2]}$, it is easy to show that they can't be $0$ at the boundary. We can decide to look at eigenfunctions without the support condition. Then, for $a\geq 0$, $x\mapsto\cos(a x)$ is an eigenfunction of $A$ (with eigenfunction $i \sqrt{\frac{|a|}{2\pi}}$) but it's obviously in $L^2$. I guess we are not in the Kansas of compact operator theory any more. Are there other eigenfunctions? (Is there a discrete spectrum?)

Let C be the operator of convolution with $\eta$ (which we may take supported on $[-2\pi,2\pi]$). Then $C\colon L^2(-\pi,\pi)\to L^2(-3\pi,3\pi)$ is compact (continuous kernel, compact intervals).  Let $R\colon L^2(-3\pi,3\pi)\to L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ be the restriction, a bounded operator.  Then $A=RC$ is compact, and $A^*A = RC^2R$ is compact and self-adjoint, hence has discrete spectrum.

I see you've changed variables, so divide all my intervals by $2\pi$.

@LiorSilberman Yes, exactly: either you restrict in the definition of your operator, and then your operator is compact and the theory is beautiful - but we do not know what the eigenfunctions are (beyond knowing that they are not anything we've discussed!), or you do not restrict in the definition of your operator, and then you have access to eigenfunctions cos(ax) (beautiful but not L^2) - and your operator is not compact, and the theory is complicated (well, to us plebs).

In the definition of $A$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}$.

Obvious variant: consider the operator $B:f\mapsto \frac{1}{2\pi^2} \left(f'\ast \frac{1}{x}\right)$. Then the Fourier transform of  $Bf$ is $|t| \widehat{f}(t)$. Hence $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |t| |\widehat{f}(t)|^2 dt = \langle \widehat{f}, \widehat{B f}(t)\rangle = \langle f,B f\rangle$, and $(Bf)(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f'(x+y)}{-y} dy$, which, for $f$ everywhere differentiable, equals $\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{(y-x)^2} dy$.

It's also obviously the case that, by asking which function $f$ with support on $[-1/2,1/2]$ (and $|f|_2=1$, $f$ absolutely continuous, etc.) minimizes $\int |t| |\widehat{f}(t)|^2 dt$, we are asking a question of uncertainty-principle type.

Asked the question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483993/uncertainty-principle-minimize-int-infty-infty-t-widehatft2-dt . Ah, maybe I can see an approach now, using precisely $\langle f,Bf\rangle = \langle Af,Af\rangle$.
