Uncertainty principle: minimize $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |t| |\widehat{f}(t)|^2 dt$ for $f$ of compact support
This is a question of uncertainty-principle type stemming from Eigenvalue of a convolution and a restriction?
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be even, absolutely continuous and supported in $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$, with $f'$ of bounded total variation. Let $|f|_2=1$. What is the minimal possible value of
$$I(f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |t| |\hat{f}(t)|^2 dt?$$
Which choice or choices of $f$ minimize $I(f)$?

Here "absolutely continuous" and "$f'$ of bounded total variation" are technical conditions that guarantee that $f(t)=O(1/t^2)$ as $t\to \pm \infty$.
PS. MathOverflow just noticed something I had forgotten, viz., I asked a question that turns out to be equivalent two years ago in Distribution $f$ such that (a) $\widehat{f}$ has compact support, (b) $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$ is minimal? . Clever robot! That question got 9 upvotes but no full answers, so it seems legitimate to ask a not-so-very-obviously equivalent question.
On another note: $f(x) = \cos(\pi x)|_{[-1/2,1/2]}$ is a natural choice - can one do better?
EDIT: Yes, one can do better - see my self-answer below.
Briefly - what I have done is give a sequence of $f$'s corresponding to eigenvectors of Toeplitz matrix (the eigenvector corresponding to the minimal eigenvalue for that matrix). It's now clear what the limit function looks like, though I haven't got an expression.
On the limit of the eigenvalues (i.e. the minimal $I(f)$), I am a bit confused. Szegő's (strong) limit theorem for Toeplitz matrices should solve the issue - but it would seem to give that the least eigenvalues tend to $0$! (Our matrices are $(a_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j\leq N}$ with $a_{i,j}=b_{i-j}=b_{j-i}$, where $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} b_n = 0$.) That does not make sense. What is going on? Update: we should really write $a_{i,j} = N a_{i-j} = N a_{j-1}$, where the sequence $a_n$ does not depend on $N$, and $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} a_n = 0$. Then Szegő's theorem just tells us that the least eigenvalues are $o(N)$ (and a positive proportion of eigenvalues for given large $N$ are $\leq \epsilon N$). That's not nearly as strong as what we want: we can see, from numerics, that the lowest eigenvalue tends to a constant, and we would like to prove what that constant is (our numerics just give us upper bounds).

Here is a possible approach. Let $B$ the linear operator such that $\widehat{Bf}(t) = |t| \widehat{f}(t)$. (Namely: $B$ is given by $Bf = f'\ast \frac{1}{2\pi^2 x}$.) We are being asked to minimize $\langle Bf, f\rangle$ given $|f|_2=1$, i.e., find the lowest eigenvalue. Since the eigenvalues are clearly all positive, this is the same as minimizing $|B f|2$. However, $$|B f|2 =  \int{-\infty}^\infty ||t| \widehat{f}(t)|^2 dt =  \int{-\infty}^\infty |t \widehat{f}(t)|^2 dt,$$ which equals both $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} |f'|_2^2$ and $- \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \langle f,f''\rangle$. (continued below)

Here I want to conclude by saying 'the eigenfunctions of $f\mapsto f'$ are the exponentials' but of course they are not of compact support. The issue is that $e^{i a x}\cdot 1_{[-b,b]}$ is almost an eigenfunction of $f\mapsto f'$, except it's not continuous at $b$ or $-b$, and $\cos(a x)\cdot 1_{[-1/2a,1/2a]}$ is continuous and almost an eigenfunction of $f\mapsto f''$, except it is not differentiable at $-1/a$ or $1/a$.

However, for $\cos(a x)\cdot 1_{[-1/2a,1/2a]}$, $|f'|_2^2$ is still meaningful, and in the sense of distributions or measures, so is $\langle f,f''\rangle$.

... though $f'\ast \frac{1}{x}$ blows up at both $-1/2a$ and $1/2a$ for $f(x) = \cos(ax) 1_{[-1/2a,1/2a]}$, meaning we have to tread carefully.

I am confused you speak of support of $f$ contained in $[-1/2,1/2]$ and $f=O(1/t^2)$.

@juan I meant $\hat{f}(t) = O(1/t^2)$.

Ah, the problem of minimizing $|f'|^2$ has a nice solution! Consider first a discretization - let us just consider $f$'s that are piecewise linear - more specifically, linear on all intervals [a/N-1/2,(a+1)/N-1/2], and 0 at -1/2 and 1/2. Then it's not hard to reduce the problem of minimizing $|f'|^2$ to that of finding the top eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix on a path graph (h/t @WillSawin for seeing this). The top eigenfunction is indeed equal to cos(x) at all a/N-1/2, 0<=a<=N. The limit is obviously $\cos(x)$.
PS. One can show one can always discretize by $|f'|_{TV}<\infty$.

My one remaining misgiving lies in the reduction of minimizing $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |t| |\hat{f}(t)|^2 dt$ to minimizing $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |t|^2 |\hat{f}(t)|^2 dt$. This wasn't really rigorous, as the space of functions we are considering was not closed under $B$. (Incidentally, that is also true for $f\mapsto f'$; notice that our solution to that problem (which does seem sound) is not an eigenfunction: $\cos'$ is not a multiple of $\cos$, though $\cos$ feels 'eigenfunctiony'.)

@ChristianRemling What you are saying is a qualitative restatement of the problem (of course we need to concentrate $\widehat{f}$ near $0$, obeying the constraints). At any rate, it seems to me that one avenue of attack is to discretize the original problem. Let me do that now. (Do you have another approach?)

Here is a half-answer - in brief, I have managed to discretize the problem in a way that gives actual valid choices of $f$ for the original problem, together with their values of $f$.
It is easy to solve the discrete problem numerically for large enough $N$ to get a good $f$ (clearly better than $\sqrt{2} \cos(\pi x)\cdot 1_{[-1/2,1/2]}$, which was a reasonable guess). Now, we want something better than a numerical solution. The discrete problem is a question on Toeplitz matrices, all of them submatrices of an infinite matrix with relatively nice coefficients. That means that I should be able to use Szegő's limit theorem to learn something about the optimal value of $I(f)$ (and possibly determine it exactly, though that may be a bit tricky).
Meta-question, though: surely this question has been considered it before? Is the answer really not known? We are just asking for the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $|f|_2=1$ and support on a unit interval $[-1/2,1/2]$ such that $\langle f,H f'\rangle$ is minimal, where $H$ is the Hilbert operator.
I don't want to reinvent the wheel, though it has been fun so far.

The challenge is to reduce the problem to a discrete problem about a symmetric operator that maps a vector space to itself, so that we can then look for eigenvalues and eigenvectors.
First steps: definition of $B$. Consider the operator $B$ given by $B f = \frac{1}{2\pi} H f' = f'\ast \frac{1}{2\pi^2 x}$, where $H$ is the Hilbert operator $H g = g\ast \frac{1}{\pi x}$. These convolutions are to be understood in the sense of Cauchy principal values:
$$Bf(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f'(x-y)}{2\pi^2 y} dy :=
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} + \int_\epsilon^\infty\right) \frac{f'(x-y)}{2\pi^2 y} dy,$$ which is well-defined for $x$ such that $f'$ is differentiable at $x$. A function of bounded variation is differentiable almost everywhere; since $f'$ is of bounded total variation, $Bf$ is defined almost everywhere.  Since the Fourier transform of $f'$ is $2\pi i t \hat{f}(t)$, and the Hilbert operator corresponds to multiplying a Fourier transform by $\mathrm{sgn}(t)/i$, the Fourier transform of $Bf$ is $|t| \widehat{f}(t)$. Hence,
$$\langle f,Bf\rangle = \langle \widehat{f}, \widehat{Bf}\rangle = 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |t| |\hat{f}(t)|^2 dt.$$
Our problem is thus to minimize $\langle f, Bf\rangle$ given that $\langle f,f\rangle = 1$.
Discretization. We will approximate our function $f$ by a piecewise linear function. We set $\delta = 1/N$ for $N$ large, and define $f_\delta(x)$ to equal $f(x)$ for $x=x_j = -1/2+\frac{j}{N}$ with $0\leq j\leq N$; in particular, $x_0=-1/2$, $x_N=1/2$, $f_\delta(x_0) = f(-1/2) = 0$ and $f_\delta(x_N)=f(1/2)=0$. We let $f_\delta(x)$ be linear for $x_j\leq x\leq x_{j+1}$, $0\leq j<N$.
It is clear that $\lim_{N\to \infty} |f_{1/N}-f|_2 = 0$ (in fact, $\lim_{N\to \infty} |f_{1/N}-f|_2= 0$, by the fundamental theorem of calculus (applicable because $f$ is absolutely continuous) and because $f'$ is bounded (by virtue of being of bounded total variation) and $\lim_{N\to \infty} |f_{1/N}'-f'|_2 = 0$ (because $f'$ is of bounded total variation $|f|_{\mathrm{TV}}$). Since the Hilbert transform is an isometry, it follows that $$\langle f_{1/N},B f_{1/N}\rangle = \langle f_{1/N}, \frac{1}{2\pi} H f_{1/N}'\rangle \to 
\langle f, \frac{1}{2\pi} H f'\rangle = \langle f, B f\rangle.$$
For $1\leq j\leq N-1$ (or $0\leq j\leq N$; it doesn't matter), let
$$b_j(f) = \int_{-1}^1 Bf_\delta(x_j+r\delta) (1-|r|) dr.$$This integral is well-defined: while $B f_\delta(x)$ can be singular at $x_j$, it grows only like $C \log |x-x_j|$ as $x\to x_j^+$ or $x\to x_j^-$, and so it remains integrable.
Then, for any function $g$ in the same space as $f_{1/N}$ (namely, $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(x)=0$ for $x\notin (-1/2,1/2)$ and $g$ piecewise linear on every interval $[x_j,x_{j+1}]$, $0\leq j\leq N$),
$$\langle g,Bf_{1/N}(x)\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^N g(x_j) b_j,$$
where the product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the usual inner product of $L^2$ functions on $\mathbb{R}$. (To see this, decompose $g$ as a linear combination of piecewise linear functions as above that are non-zero at exactly one $x_j$.)
Describing our discretized operator explicitly. Symmetry. Let us work out what the operator $B_N:(x_j)_{1\leq j<N} \mapsto (b_j)_{1\leq j<N}$ is exactly. It will be particularly important to show that it is symmetric.
Let us look at $x = x_j + r \delta$ with $0<r\leq 1$. The contribution of $d_j = \frac{1}{\delta} (f_\delta(x_{j+1}) - f_\delta(x_{j}))$ (the value of $f_\delta'(x)$ for $x_j<x<x_{j+1}$) to $Bf_\delta(x)$ is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \int_{r\delta}^{(1-r)\delta} \frac{d_j}{-y} dy
= - \frac{d_j}{2\pi^2} \log \frac{1-r}{r},$$
if $r\leq 1/2$, and
$$\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \int_{(1-r)\delta}^{r \delta} \frac{d_j}{y} dy
= \frac{d_j}{2\pi^2} \log \frac{r}{1-r};$$
if $r>1/2$; in other words, it is always $\frac{d_j}{2\pi^2} \log \frac{r}{1-r}$. The contribution of $d_{j+k}$, $k\ne 0$, to $Bf_\delta(x)$ is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \int_{(k-r)\delta}^{(k+1-r) \delta} \frac{d_{j+k}}{-y} dy
= - \frac{d_{j+k}}{2\pi^2} \log \frac{k+1-r}{k-r}$$
if $k>0$, and
$$\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \int_{(|k|+r-1)\delta}^{(|k|+r) \delta} \frac{d_{j+k}}{y} dy
= \frac{d_{j+k}}{2\pi^2} \log \frac{|k|+r}{|k|+r-1}$$
if $k<0$; in other words, it is always $\frac{d_{j+k}}{2\pi^2} \log \frac{k-r}{k+1-r}$.
We see, then, that the contribution of $d_j$ to $b_j$ is
$$ \frac{d_j}{2\pi^2} \left(\int_0^1 (1-r) \log \frac{r}{1-r} dr +
\int_0^1 r  \log \frac{1-r}{2-r} dr\right) = \frac{d_j}{2\pi^2}
\cdot (- 2\log 2),
$$
whereas the contribution of $d_{j-1}$ to $b_j$ is
$$\frac{d_{j-1}}{2\pi^2}\left(\int_0^1 r \log \frac{r}{1-r} dr + \int_0^1 (1-r) \log \frac{-1-r}{-r} dr \right) = \frac{d_{j-1}}{2\pi^2}\cdot 2\log 2.
$$
The contribution of $d_{j+k}$ with $k\geq 1$ or $k<-1$ to $b_j$ is $\frac{d_{j+k}}{2\pi^2} (c_{k+1} + c_k')$, where $$c_k = \int_0^1 r \log \frac{k-r}{k+1-r} dr,\;\;\;\;\;\;
c_k' = \int_0^1 (1-r) \log \frac{k-r}{k+1-r} dr.
$$
It is clear that $-c_k=c_{-k}'$ for $|k|\geq 1$, by a change of variables $r\mapsto 1-r$.
Thus: the contribution of $f_\delta(x_{j+1})$ to  $b_j$ is
$$\frac{f_\delta(x_{j+1})}{2\pi^2 \delta} (- 2\log 2 - (c_2 + c_1') ) = 
\frac{f_\delta(x_{j+1})}{2\pi^2 \delta} (- 2\log 2 - (c_2 - c_{-1}) )
,$$
the contribution of $f_\delta(x_j)$ is
$$\frac{f_\delta(x_{j})}{2\pi^2 \delta} 4 \log 2,$$
whereas the contribution of $f_\delta(x_{j-1})$ is
$$\frac{f_\delta(x_{j-1})}{2\pi^2 \delta} (-2\log 2+(c_{-1}-c_{2})).
$$
We can already see that the coefficients for the contributions of $f_\delta(x_{j+1})$ and $f_\delta(x_{j-1})$ are the same.
For $|k|\geq 2$, the contribution of $f_\delta(x_{j+k})$ to $b_j$ is
$$\frac{f_\delta(x_{j+1})}{2\pi^2 \delta} (c_k-c_{-k+1}-c_{k+1}+c_{-k}),
$$
and of course see that this remains the same if we replace $k$ by $-k$. In other words, the matrix is symmetric.
This is not at all surprising - in fact it follows from the definition of the operator $B_N$ as describing the symmetric operator $B$ (in the sense that $\langle g,Bf_{1/N}(x)\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^N g(x_j) b_j$). Still, it is an important sanity check. In the same way, we can deduce from the definition of $B_N$ that it is positive definite - and we can observe it by looking at the entries of the matrix we have just determined. This is the symmetric matrix $M_{1\leq i,j<N}$ with entries $M_{i,j} = b_{j-i}$, where $b_0 =4 \log 2$, $b_1 = b_{-1} = -2\log 2 - (c_2+c_{-1})$ and $b_k = b_{-k} = c_k-c_{-k+1}-c_{k+1}+c_{-k}$. (The operator $B_N$ is given by $\frac{1}{2\pi^2\delta} M$.) It is easy to show that $b_k$ is negative for $k\ne 0$ (because $\log$ is convex-down) and that $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty b_m = 0$; hence, $b_0$ is greater than the absolute value of any finite sum of $b_m$'s with $m\ne 0$, and, in particular, greater than $\sum_{j\ne i} |M_{i,j}|$ for any $j$, and so our matrix $M$ is positive definite.
Explicitly, for $|m|\geq 2$ (and $m=-1$, if we agree $0 \log 0 = 0$)
$$c_m = \frac{m^2-1}{2} \log \frac{m}{m-1} - \frac{(m+1)^2}{2} \log \frac{m+1}{m} + \frac{1}{2}.$$
and so, for $|m|\geq 2$,
$$\begin{aligned}c_m - c_{m+1} &= \frac{m^2-1}{2} \log \frac{m}{m-1} - \frac{2 (m+1)^2-1}{2} \log \frac{m+1}{m} + \frac{(m+2)^2}{2} \log \frac{m+2}{m+1}\\ &= \frac{m^2-1}{2} \log \frac{m^2}{m^2-1}
+ \frac{(m+2)^2}{2} \log \frac{(m+1)^2-1}{(m+1)^2} + \log \frac{m+1}{m}
\end{aligned}$$ and hence, for $k\geq 2$,
$$b_k = 
(2-k^2) \log \left(1 -\frac{1}{k^2}\right) + \frac{(2+k)^2}{2} \log \left(1-\frac{1}{(1+k)^2}
\right)+ \frac{(2-k)^2}{2} \log \left(1-\frac{1}{(1-k)^2}\right),
$$
whereas $b_1 = b_{-1} = \frac{9}{2}\log 3 - 8 \log 2$ and $b_0 = 4\log 2$.
Eigenvalues and eigenfunctions. Now we just need to determine the lowest eigenvalue of $B$ for a given $N$, and the corresponding eigenvector.
For $N=100,250,1000$, the lowest eigenvalue is
$$0.369270...,\;\;\;\;\;\; 0.368850...,\;\;\;\;\;\; 0.368614...,$$
respectively. (This is just with numpy; I'll redo the values with interval arithmetic later.) As per all of the above, these are actual upper bounds on the minimal value of $I(f)$ in our original problem, since we are dealing with a special case of our original problem, not just some sort of discrete toy model.
We should compare these bounds to what we would obtain if we started by applying Cauchy-Schwarz
$$|\langle f,B f\rangle|\leq |f|_2 |B f|_2 = |B f|_2 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sqrt{\langle H(f'), H(f')\rangle} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sqrt{\langle f',f'\rangle} = \frac{1}{2\pi} |f'|_2$$
and then minimized $|f'|_2$, given our constraint on the support. The optimal $f$ is then $f = \sqrt{2} \cos(\pi x)|_{[-1/2,1/2]}$, for which we have
$$|Bf|_2 = \frac{1}{2\pi} |f'|_2 = \frac{1}{2}.$$
So, what we have got now is clearly better.
Here are plots of $f$ for $N=100,250,1000$ (in red, blue and purple). They are well-nigh indistinguishable.

Here is a comparison of $f$ (for $N=1000$, in purple) with $\sqrt{2} \cos(\pi x)$ (in green):

Now $f$ looks vaguely like the entropy function, as a friend pointed out. It's not the same, though. Here is a comparison with $E(x) = -\sqrt{\frac{18}{15-\pi^2}} ((x+1/2)\log(x+1/2) + (1/2-x) \log(1/2-x))$ (in green):

As you can see, they are much closer, but they are different enough that they are likely not the same function in the limit. (To know for sure, it would be enough to compute the Hilbert transform of $((x+1/2) \log(x+1/2) + (1/2-x) \log(1/2-x))' = \log(x+1/2) - \log(1/2-x)$ -- that seems extremely doable.)
In fact, just eyeballing, it would seem that $f$ tends to a function that behaves like $C \sqrt{x}$ near $x=0$, and like $C \sqrt{1-x}$ near $x=0$. What that function is remains a mystery to me. Again: how could this question still be open?
Determining the limit of the eigenvalues as $N\to \infty$ seems easier, in that there's a tool that seems made for the task - Szegő's limit theorem. (Thanks to the applied-math friend who pointed this out; I am ignorant.) In brief - we need to look at
$$w(\theta) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty b_k.$$ (Perhaps there is a nice expression for $w(\theta)$? It's not immediately clear.)

Incidentally, another way to see that $\sqrt{2}\cos(\pi x)$ is not the correct solution is that, assuming that it is the minimizer, we should have $\langle f, Bf\rangle = |Bf|_2 = \frac12$. But for this function the value of $\langle f, Bf\rangle$ can be computed explicitly to be (according to Wolfram) $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x \cos^2(\pi x)}{\pi^2 ( 1/4 - t^2)^2} ~dx = \frac1\pi \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(t)}{t} ~dt - \frac{2}{\pi^2} \approx 0.38685 $$
